# What is the best way to write a two column query in LINQ to Entity 6? And save the results to two different variables?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

How would you write "SELECT col.a, col.b FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1"  in LINQ to Entity 6 so that you could save col.a into variable A and col.b into variable B. You can do this with SqlReader by retrieving the index or column name, but with LINQ to Entity it is returned as one object. When returning a two field LINQ query to a list, both field are saved to the first index of the list and can only be accessed as the same list element. Is it standard to create two LINQ queries, one for each variable? Or am I missing part of the process?

Current query:

```
var result = (from col in cxt.Table 
              where col.ID == "1" 
              select new {col.a, col.b}).ToList();
```

Comment: Please give an example of your table and what you want.

Comment: If my LINQ query is:

Comment: If my LINQ query is: 'var result = (from col in cxt.Table where col.ID == "1" select new {col.a, col.b}).ToList();' How do I extract the values of col.a and col.b**separately** from the result List? So I could assign them to different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting exactly one record to return from database then what you can do:

```
var result = cxt.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == "1"); 
//Notice that might be null if has not result

var a = result.a;
var b = result.b;
```

*Will look very similar in query syntax but I think this method syntax neater in this case*

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was missing the step of how to pulling the field values out. I understand much better how it works now.

Comment: @Ian - great :) Also, have a look at SO's linq documentation - its good and has nice short examples

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. But selecting two variable by `Linq` is not so hard.

```
var value = (from ta in db.YourTable
             where ta.ID = id
             select new {
                 A = ta.a,
                 B = ta.b
             }).FirstOrDefault();
var a = value.A;
var b = value.B;
```

If you use `ToList()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`, you will get a list contain zero or more objects. You can simply use a loop to get field from each object.

```
forach(var value in values)
{
    var a = value.A;
    var b = value.B;
}
```